# The flutter image_picker plugin restarts the app every time when an image is picked on Redmi Note 9

Tags: flutter, flutter-image-picker

This happens only in Redmi Note 9. I've read the image_picker documentation and it says this occurs when there is not enough memory in the device and it causes to restart of the MainActivity in the Flutter app. But the device has enough memory.

Is there any fix or any alternatives for this package?

Answer (score 0):

Try This sample of Code, this worked for me:

Code :

```
Future<void> retrieveLostData() async {
  final LostData response =
      await picker.getLostData();
  if (response.isEmpty) {
    return;
  }
  if (response.file != null) {
    setState(() {
      if (response.type == RetrieveType.video) {
        _handleVideo(response.file);
      } else {
        _handleImage(response.file);
      }
    });
  } else {
    _handleError(response.exception);
  }
}
```

Comment: This can be used only to retrieve lost data on a restart, I need to stop the app from restarting when picking an image.